# ¿Como podría definir una función en la que pueda enviar dos argumentos?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo definir un función que reciba como argumentos una cadena y un objeto?

La función en este caso se llama `template` y esto podría ser un ejemplo de su funcionamiento:

```
template("Hola [nombre], tu saldo es [saldo]", { nombre: "Henry", saldo: 5000000 });
```

> "Hola Henry, tu saldo es 5000000"

Comment: Henry, muestranos que has intentado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo utilizando una expresiones regulares.
Luego, para reemplazar la coincidencia con la propiedad adecuada del objeto, puedes hacer uso de la posibilidad que da el método `replace` de especificar una función para obtener el texto sustituto:

```js
function template(pattern, values){
  var re = /\[(\w+)\]/g;
  return pattern.replace(re, 
    function(m, key) {
      return values[key]; 
    });
}

var result = template("Hola [nombre], tu saldo es [saldo]", { nombre: "Henry", saldo: 5000000 }); // => "Hola Henry, tu saldo es 5000000"
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Excelente como queda de condensado el código con el uso de                    expresiones regulares, creo que ese tipo de manejo es indispensable para la optimización de las funciones.

Answer (score 0):

No responde directamente a tu pregunta, pero, considera usar para esta tarea [**`String Template Literals`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) (**`Plantillas de cadena de texto`**) (`ES2015`).

**Tagged Template literals**

> A more advanced form of template literals are tagged template
>   literals. Tags allow you to parse template literals with a function.
>   The first argument of a tag function contains an array of string
>   values. The remaining arguments are related to the expressions. In the
>   end, your function can return your manipulated string (or it can
>   return something completely different as described in the next
>   example). The name of the function used for the tag can be named
>   whatever you want.

**`Traducción`**

> Una forma más avanzada de plantillas de texto. Los tags te permiten
>   **parsear plantillas de texto con una función**. El primer argumento de la
>   función contiene una lista de strings. Los argumentos restantes están
>   relacionados con las expresiones. Al final, tu función puede devolver
>   el string manipulado ( O puede devolver algo completamente distinto
>   como se describe en el siguiente ejemplo)...

```js
function template(strings, ...keys) {
  return (values) => {
    return keys.reduce((arr, key, i) => {
      var value = values[key];
      arr.push(value, strings[i + 1]);
      return arr;
    }, strings.slice(0,1)).join('');
  };
}

var GreetTemplateGenerator = template`Hola soy ${'nombre'} y cobro ${'dinero'}!`;

var FavouriteColorTemplateGenerator = template`Mi color favorito es el ${'color'}`;

var greetGeneratedTemplate = GreetTemplateGenerator({ nombre: 'Jose', dinero: '5M' });

var fcolorGeneratedTemplate = FavouriteColorTemplateGenerator({ color: '#ffbb00' });

console.log(greetGeneratedTemplate);
console.log(fcolorGeneratedTemplate);
```

La función es una copia casi exacta de la que hay en la [fuente en Inglés](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals).